# Google Sign-in: Token Expired

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

I am using [google sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web) to allow users to sign-up for my website. The issue I'm having is that my sign-up process is quite lengthy (could take more than 1 hour), and I don't send any information to my backend before the end of the sign-up. However, my the google token expires after 1 hour. I want to avoid the client having to send more than 1 request to google for authentication.

Is there any way to exchange this token for a long-lived token on the backend? I know facebook oauth offers that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to exchange this token for a long-lived token on the
>   backend?

No, using the referenced article.

Yes, if you also request the Refresh Token during authorization with Google.  This requires that the OAuth Flow runs on your webserver.

The Refresh Token can create (request) an Access Token when required. Therefore you don't care about how long your backend takes.

You cannot do the reverse: request a Refresh Token from an Access Token.

Comment: Hi John, do you mean accessing a Google endpoint that you will pass an access token, and a new token will be sent to you and you will use that token to access the Google API services endpoints?

Comment: @chitgoks - You can use a Refresh Token to obtain a new Access Token. You cannot refresh an Access Token without the Refresh Token.

Comment: thanks for the info john. been looking for some sample and code on how to do this using basic http post. do you have a working sample perhaps?

Comment: @chitgoks - There are lots of samples on the Internet. My personal website has several https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-refresh-access-token/

Comment: thank you i will check. the examples i have seen are only for initial google sign in. once the access token expires, i have to re-sign in using the form. have not found code that silently creates a new access token (using refresh token). Well, they're mostly using the api. i am after basic code using ajax url

Comment: @chitgoks - I provided a link for you to my website which renews Access Tokens.